# Javascript Closure: function returning "undefined" instead of a value

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to learn JavaScript closure and got confused by an output. I am sure that this should be easy and quick to answer.
When I run following code snippet, I get "undefined" as an output.

```
function foo(){
    var x = 5;
    function bar(){
        return x; // returning value of x
    }
    baz(bar); // output is "undefined"
}

function baz(fn){
    fn();
}
```

However if i run following code, then correct value of x is printed on console.

```
function foo(){
    var x = 5;
    function bar(){
        console.log(x); // printing value of x on console
    }
    baz(bar); // output is 5
}

function baz(fn){
    fn();
}
```

So i am confused as to why when value of x is returned output is "undefined", but when value of x is printed on console then correct value of x is printed. Really appreciate if someone can explain this behavior.

Comment: `return  baz(bar);`. The value should be returned form function otherwise it is `undefined` by default. In second case, you're logging the value, not returning it.

Comment: And also `return fn()`

Comment: Well your function `bar` in the example two, prints X. In the example one it returns X. Returning X to function `baz` doesn nothing or rather you get a value in it but you never neither return it nor print it.

Comment: Also not much "closure" work here honestly. You just have function calls in functions.

Comment: @Tushar - Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Jonasw - Thanks for quick response and additions to correct solution.

Comment: @Dellirium - Understood the mistake, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Your code to this :-

```
function foo(){
var x = 5;
function bar(){
    return x; // returning value of x
}
return baz(bar); // returns 5
}

function baz(fn){
  return fn();
}
console.log(foo())
```

You were not returning the values returned by "bar" function in your "baz" function, and also "foo" function should return the value returned by baz function.You can hold it in a variable or console the value returned by foo.